# Would a magnetic needle standing on it's point on a magnet be more stable than the same needle stood on a non-magnetic surface?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity

So I was watching MinutePhysics' video 'How long can you balance a pencil?' and it turned out to not be for very long.

Would introducing a magnet to the equation make for different results?

We can assume the magnet and non-magnetic surface are both uniform and perfectly flat, and that the needle is uniform to a 'sharp' tip (sharp to a point where material compress-ability is not a factor, so it would technically have a microscopic flat surface).

I think it would help due to the magnet securing the flat portion of the needle against the magnet evenly, but then again, with a slight offset, it would act on the shaft of the needle with any amount of horizontal propagation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that you're aware that all of this is described by differential equations. For instance, [here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_pendulum) the equations for the inverted pendulum. What you seem to be interested in are the cases where the angle $\theta$ remains a constant.

In the case of the needle on a flat surface, no magnetism, there are two steady states.

A) The needle stays upright *forever*

B) The needle falls down and then stays on its side *forever*

You can classify these "equilibria" by linearizing the differential equation about the point. Look [here](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/system/nonlinear/linearization/linearization.html) for a good introduction.

The fixed point in A is an *unstable* fixed point. However, the point in B is *stable*. This means that slight variations in the angle $\theta$ that allows the needle to stay in A will force it to go to B.

I'd think of it like this. There is only *one* angle that allows a needle to stay upright. Namely, $\theta={{\pi} \over 2}$. However, there are an *infinite* number of other points that allow the steady state angle to become $0$ or $\pi$. So even a microscopic change in $\theta$ from ${{\pi} \over 2}$ to ${{\pi} \over 2} +\epsilon$ will move the angle from a steady state angle for A to a steady point angle for B.

What happens when there is a magnet? The magnet will pull in the same direction as gravity. The difference will be the strength at which the magnetic force pulls. At the bottom of the needle, the force will be quite strong, while the force at the top will be weaker. In fact, the magnet will "fix" one end of the needle about the surface of the magnet! This will quite literally make it an inverted pendulum. Therefore, all the above analysis applies.

Comment: Zach, your answer is better than my short snippet, no question, but where's the magnet involvement that the OP asks about? In other words, could you include a term in the D.E. (or  the Langranian above that) that allows for a magnetic field? Apologies if I misunderstand your answer, though.

Comment: @AcidJazz That's kind of my fault. The case is exactly the same with a magnet. I'll address that :)

Comment: I searched around before giving my "answer", but i could not find anything about real life magnets, how isotropic the field would be in reality. All the examples are given assuming perfect fields. I just don't know enough about magnets to tell if the domains line up as perfectly as we learn about, somehow I doubt they do....

Comment: @AcidJazz They probably don't, but I assume the best case. It'd be easy to prove that the magnet falls over if the field is non-uniform, so I focus on the harder case. (The OP says things like "perfectly flat" which makes me think a theoretical answer was appropriate here)

Answer (score 2):

This, to me, depends on how uniform a magnetic field your magnet creates in reality.  I am no expert, but if it's not, I can imagine you are doubling your chances of the needle falling, both from the unevenness of the surface and the possible unevenness of the magnetic field.

Sorry for the short answer, but I hope you get a better one.